# Logical and Arithmetic shift's output

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift

Here's a tiny java program

```
public class otherclass {
public static void main(String[]args){
        byte a=-5;

        byte d= (byte) (a>>>1);
        System.out.println(d);
        byte e= (byte) (a>>>2);
        System.out.println(e);
        byte f= (byte) (a>>1);
        System.out.println(f);
        byte g= (byte) (a>>2);
        System.out.println(g);
}
}
```

output:

```
-3
-2
-3
-2
```

The second two outputs (those -3 and -2 of the logical shifts) I understand.

negative 5 is `11111011`

arithmetic shift shifts to the right and the extra added bit on the left is like the MSB. So one shift makes `11111101` which is negative 3. Negative two is also fine.

The logical shift is supposed to add zeros to the left. `11111011` should become `01111101` which is 125. How does it also output negative 3?

Comment: Note that the shift occurs on a value of type `int` (4 bytes).

Comment: ummm what do you mean? It doesn't work on byte variables?

Comment: its an integral type represented by a specific amount of bytes determined by which type. for example, `int` has 32 bytes. `short` is 16 bytes, and `byte` is 8. I don't understand @SotiriosDelimanolis comment either though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing piece of information is that Java promotes the values to `int` when bit-shifting them, called binary numeric promotion.  The `byte` values are promoted to `int` before they are shifted, then the shift occurs, then they are cast back to `byte`.

```
-5 as byte  : 11111011
-5 as int   : 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011
Bit shifted : 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
```

The zero is shifted in, but the cast back to `byte` discards it all but the last 8 bits anyway.

```
Cast to byte: 11111101 (-3)
```

If you would like the `>>>` operation to behave as if there were no binary numeric promotion, then you must mask out the final 8 bits from the promoted `int`.

```
byte d= (byte) ((a & 0xFF)>>>1);
System.out.println(d);
byte e= (byte) ((a & 0xFF)>>>2);
System.out.println(e);
```

Output:

```
125
62
```

What's happening here:

```
-5 as byte  : 11111011
-5 as int   : 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111011
Bit masked  : 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111011
Bit shifted : 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111101
```

The zero is shifted in as before, but the cast back to `byte` discards it all but the last 8 bits anyway.

```
Cast to byte: 01111101 (125)
```

Note that this would occur with `>>>` and with `>>`, so only do the bit-and with `0xFF` on the `>>>` operations.

Comment: I see. Well that answers the question. Thanks for that. But now I need to know a way to make the shift without letting java do this promotion. I want to do the shift on the byte as it is.

Comment: heh oh well. I understand what you say, only that it's the first time for me to encounter "masking". I think I need to learn a bit about it first. ...thank you so much :D